# Return new function with binded arguments

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a new function with bounded arguments, similar to JavaScript's `function.prototype.bind` method.

I know you can do this by importing variables into an anonymous function but would love to know if there is functionality for this.

```php
$func2 = function() uses ($arg1, $arg2) {
   func($arg1, $arg2);
}

# What im looking for..
$func2 = func.bind(null, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: maybe this is something you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/de/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: Your example is not the best you could add.. you can simply call `$func2 = func($arg1, $arg2)`

Comment: Did you mean this http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php or http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php?